# PHP: validate the lines of a "text" file while extracting some stats at the same time?

Tags: php, validation, text, callback

I have a file (from a POST request) that I would like to validate against some constraints:

- All lines must be composed of ASCII printable characters only.
- There must be at least one XYZ record (lines that start with `@XYZ` ).
- There must be at most 999999 XYZ records

For that purpose I made a generic function that reads a file by chunks and pass each line to a callback for validation:

```php
/*
 * Iterates over each line of the file, passing them to the callback function for validation.
 * When the callback function returns false, or when there is an error,
 * the validation process ends.
 * 
 * @param string   $filename       The name of the file to validate.
 * @param callable $callback       The callback function to use for validating each line.
 * @param string   $line_delimiter The line-ending delimiter (default is "\n").
 * @param integer  $buffer_size    The maximum number of bytes to read from the file at a time (default is 8192).
 *
 * @return Returns true when $callback returned true for each line, false if not, and NULL on error.
 *
 * @warning When $buffer_size is not large enough to contain a whole line, $callback will validate chunks of lines.
 */
function validate_file_lines($filename, $callback, $line_delimiter = "\n", $buffer_size = 8192)
{
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $is_valid = (false === $handle ? null : true);

    $remainder = '';

    while ( $is_valid && !feof($handle) )
    {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $buffer_size);

        if ( false === $buffer )
        {
            $is_valid = null;
        }
        else
        {
            $lines_array = explode($line_delimiter, $buffer);
            $lines_array_key_last = count($lines_array) - 1;

            $lines_array[0] = $remainder . $lines_array[0];

            if ( $lines_array_key_last !== 0 )
            {
                $remainder = $lines_array[$lines_array_key_last];
                unset($lines_array[$lines_array_key_last]);
            }

            foreach ( $lines_array as $line )
            {
                $is_valid = $callback($line);
                if ( ! $is_valid )
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    @fclose($handle);
    return $is_valid;
}
```

Now, using it, I'm trying to validate a file, for example:

```
HEAD good
@XYZ 1
@XYZ 1
%END

HEAD better
@XYZ 2 2
%END
```

```php
$xyz_count = 0;
$xyz_min = 1;
$xyz_max = 999999;

$is_valid_line = function($line) use(&$xyz_count, $xyz_max) {
    $is_valid = true;
    if ( ctype_print($line) )
    {
        if ( substr($line, 0, 6) === '@XYZ ' )
        {
            ++$xyz_count;
            $is_valid = $xyz_count <= $xyz_max;
        }
    }
    else if ( '' !== @$line[0] )
    {
        $is_valid = false;
    }
    return $is_valid;
};

var_dump(
    validate_file_lines('file.txt', $is_valid_line) && $xyz_count >= $xyz_min
);
```

The current output is:

```php
bool(false)
```

While I'm expecting:

```php
bool(true)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

###### ASIDE

Does the SPL provide any class for iterating over file lines?

Comment: I'd suggest adding some debug output and creating some test cases. The debug output might show the line and true/false for each thing you're testing. Your first test case should be pretty simple & get bigger & more complex until you find the bug. <strike>As far as iterating over file lines, I'd say `fread` is that function</strike> - I though fread was line by line but I was wrong. I'd prefer that over loading all lines into memory & looping over array, especially since you expect potentially very large files.

Comment: Also, I think `fread()` returns false if no more lines, so you should be able to `while (($buffer = fread($handle)) !== false)`

Comment: `fgets()` its fgets! not fread(). https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Comment: and your `substr($line, 0, 6) === '@XYZ '` ... the length should be 5, not 6. `@XYZ ` is 5 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `substr()` needs to be 5 chars, not 6. You can use `fgets()` to read by line. Here's a barebones solution that might probably work. And your mode should just be `r`

Also, you might add debug printing to show where errors are happening.

```php
<?php
$fh = fopen($filename, 'r');
$valid = true;
$xyz_count = 0;
while ($valid && $line = fgets($fh)){
    if (!ctype_print($line))$valid = false;
    if (substr($line, 0, 5) == '@XYZ ')$xyz_count++;
    if ($xyz_count >= $xyz_max)$valid = false;

    // if (!$valid)echo "LINE (fail): {$line}";

}
if ($xyz_count === 0)$valid = false;
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Thank you @Reed, the substring size got past my eyes when looking for the problem in the code.

Comment: I've been doing some benchmarks with `fgets`, `stream_get_line` and `fread+explode`, and the latter is the fastest. My main concern about `fgets` is that the file can potentially be a binary file; is it safe to `fgets` in this case?

Comment: @Fravadona, I hadn't considered a binary file. I don't know, but I think your concern is valid and the fread/explode is probably safer. In your explode, be sure to consider `explode(["\r\n", "\n"])` since some systems / files use `\r\n` to represent new lines, if memory serves. You can provide a length to fgets(), but I feel like that kind of defeats the purpose in your case.